# How do i capture a variable from a text file with a batch script?

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file, cmd

Hi I'm trying to write a batch script that reads a long text file, finds a line that says:

Location: xxxxxxxx

And saves xxxxxxxx (only) as a variable that i can use later in the script.

xxxxxxxx is an ID and there is nothing else on that line.

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the requirement that it has to be batch only?   If you could use tools such as cygwin and grep/sed/awk ... the puzzle would appear to be quite easy ...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using anything other than batch.

Comment: This is actually not a question but a task request; have you done any research, have you tried anything on your own? please share your attempts...

Comment: It looks like a combination of recipes from this page might help:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php

We seem to see a "StartsWith" to find lines that begin with "Location:" and then a "SplitString" to split by the ':' delimiter and then a "Triim Left" to remove any white space.

My opinion though is that it is a lot of work as opposed to other languages such as JavaScript, Python, SED/AWK etc

Comment: @Kolban Looks like a possible solution. i'll have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @aschipfl yes i have

Comment: @aschipfl nothing i have tried achieves the desired result.

Comment: The commands you'll probably need to be familiar with are `for /f`, `findstr`, and `set`, and possibly the `pipe` (`|`) redirector.  See if you can string those together into the command you want.

Comment: @Roman - The SO crowd is much more responsive if you post some code that you have tried. It does not matter how badly it fails.

Comment: Please post your code and describe what you have problems with; in addition, please clarify whether the line of text always looks exactly like your sample, especially with respect to (white-)spaces...

Comment: So, want you to "find a line that says Location: xxxxxxxx" `findstr "Location:" textFile.txt` "and saves xxxxxxxx (only)", that is, the second token separated by space, and execute this command `for /F "tokens option" %%a in ('the command') do` "and save it as a variable" `set "variable=%%a"` **?** It should be pretty simple...

Comment: @Roman ==> Edit your question and post what did you tried as code until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, too.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('type longtextfile.txt ^|findstr /b "Location"') do set location=%a
echo %location%
```

EDIT: Adding Aacini's more efficient way of doing this:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('findstr /b "Location" longtextfile.txt') do set location=%a
echo %location%
```

Comment: Ok. I'll give this a try as well.

Comment: Just a comment: this construct: `'type longtextfile.txt ^|findstr /b "Location"'` is executed running _two copies_ of the 400KB cmd.exe file (one for each side of the pipe), so it is _much slower_ than the no-pipe equivalent: `'findstr /b "Location" longtextfile.txt'`. If this line is executed many times, the time difference may be huge!

Answer (score 0):

There are just a few standard Windows commands required for this simple task:

```
@echo off
set "TextFile=C:\Temp\Text file to search for location.txt"
if not exist "%TextFile%" echo Can't find file: "%TextFile%"& exit /B
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%I in ("%TextFile%") do (
    if /I "%%I" == "Location" (
        set "Location=%%J"
        goto FoundLocation
    )
)
echo No location found in file: "%TextFile%"
exit /B

:FoundLocation
echo Location is: %Location%
```

On second line the name of the text file with path must be defined.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: Awesome! You made my day! Thanks!